# How to get $this->webroot work in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I had this piece of code in my `services.ctp` file which was working fine before in CakePHP 2.3.10.

```
href="<?php echo $this->webroot . 'intro/services/1'; ?>
```

I just copied this file into CakePHP 3.0.0 and it's no longer working and throwing the following error message

> Error: C:\apache2\htdocs\myprojxxxx\webroot\Helper could not be found.

what's different with this `$this->webroot` in CakePHP 3.0 ?

Please help!

Answer (score 18):

You need to use this:

```
href="<?php echo $this->request->webroot . 'intro/services/1'; ?>
```

This will work with cakephp 3.0

Answer (score 3):

In cakephp 4.x you need to use this:

```
href="<?php echo $this->Url->webroot.'/intro/services/1'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you should have done it in the first place, as such "hard-coded" URLs are very inflexible in comparison to URL arrays, where it's the connected routes that define the generated URLs at a single point in your application, allowing you to easily make changes wihout having to apply modifications throughout the whole application.

That being said, the magic `$webroot` property is gone (check [**the migration guide**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#view-class)), its value can be retrieved directly via [**the `View::$request` object**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#path-information).

You should however use `Router::url()`, the `UrlHelper`, or one of the `HtmlHelper` methods instead:

```
\Cake\Routing\Router::url(['controller' => 'Intro', 'action' => 'services', 1])
```

```
$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Intro', 'action' => 'services', 1])
```

```
$this->Html->link('Title', ['controller' => 'Intro', 'action' => 'services', 1])
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Generating URLs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Url](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Html > Creating Links](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links)**

Answer (score 0):

Form me in cake 3.9 that work:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->Url->build('/img/logo_app.png');  ?>" style="width:250px" />
```